# Netbeans IDE 7.2.1 Plugins

Tags: plugins, netbeans, netbeans-7.2

I am running the 
[Netbeans 7.2.1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/evQDG.png)  < -- image

I like to install CVS plugin using NetBeans IDE Update Center. When I searched it on Update Center this is the only result shown, see image -> [NetBeans IDE Update Center](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KwhVA.png), the CVS plugin is not available. Is there anyway I can install the plugin without using the Update Center?

Comment: Have you tried to just [download](http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/48917/find-files-in-favorites) it?

Comment: I was looking for the CVS plugin but it was not there in the Update Center

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. Your image shows an entirely different plugin.

Comment: I updated the post. I was looking for the CVS plugin which is not found in the Update Center. I was asking if we can install or add it manual :)

Comment: [Try this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54725150/apache-netbeans-10-cvs-plugin-not-available)

Comment: @DrZoo yes thank you, but it is not compatible.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't update to a newer version or use another IDE like IntelliJ or Eclipse?